# Can companies be held liable for people attempting to imitate advertising stunts?

Tags: liability, advertisements

I own a small apparel company that operates an e-commerce shop. Our target demographic is young adults, and as such our brand and marketing material features an edgy and cool style. A lot of our material features various kinds of stunts, e.g. motorcycle tricks, backflips, freeclimbing, etc. We also have a section of our site where people can submit videos, and each week we choose to feature someone's video. These videos can be anything and don't have to include any kinds of stunts. However, I've had several people warn me that if a kid severely injures himself or dies while trying to make a video or get a cool picture to post on social media, our company could be held liable. To what extent is this valid concern? Is this something that is a common issue, and if so, what are the usual results?

Comment: There must be some amusing case law behind this.  I can't imagine the top-shelf ad producers for new cars enjoy putting the "Professional driver, do not attempt" warning on screen every time they show a car in motion....